# Methane remote sensing?

Tags: remote-sensing, methane, greenhouse-gases

I'm trying to compile a list of remote sensing (Earth observing satellite) instruments capable of detecting methane in the atmosphere or near surface of Earth. After some search I have found:

- Japanese Greenhouse gases observing satellite ([GOSAT](http://www.gosat.nies.go.jp/en/)), launched 2009, measuring CO2 and CH4.
- [European Sentinel 5 and Sentinel 5 Precursor](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/c-missions/copernicus-sentinel-5), measuring wide variety of atmospheric contents, 5P to be launched in 2016.
- Beginning private company [GHGSAT](http://www.ghgsat.com), measuring greenhouse gas (GHG) and air quality gas (AQG) emissions.

Are there any other satellites?

Answer (score 6):

I found a great paper named [Remote Sensing of Particulate Pollution from Space: Have We Reached the Promised Land?](http://www.nsstc.uah.edu/sundar/papers/2009/AWMA-proof.pdf) and collected some remote sensing instruments doing CH4 measurement in the chart below.

It contains the information about the satellite, orbit types, instrument and the data time-range.

```
Satellite       Orbit       Instrument    Years

Nimbus-7        Polar       SAMS          1978-1983     
UARS            L56.9       CLAES         1991-1993     
UARS            L56.9       HALOE         1991-2005     
ADEOS           PS          IMG           1996-1997     
Terra           PS          MOPITT        1999-            
AQUA            PS          AIRS          2002-            
AURA            PS          HRDLS         2003-            
Envisat         PS          SCIAMACHY     2007-
```

Comment: It definitely helps a lot. But the paper is from year 2009, so maybe we can find something additional.

Comment: This website(http://www.temis.nl/climate/methane.html) may give you a direct impression about the distribution and variation of CH4 in global scale.

Comment: And its data were derived from GOAST and SCIAMMCHY.